# Testing date/userdefault streak tracking

Tags: swift, userdefaults

I want to track streaks in my Swift app. I placed the following code in Scene Delegate. It all runs happily, but if I take my app out of my pocket the following day, the loginCount has not incremented.

Question 1: Is there anything wrong with my code?

Question 2: How can I simulate/unit test 'tomorrow', with the UserDefault element in play too?

```
    let myCalendar = Calendar.current
    let launchedBefore = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "launchedBefore")

    if launchedBefore{
       var logins = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "loginCount")
       if let lastLogin = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "lastLoginDate") as? Date
        {  
           if !myCalendar.isDateInToday(lastLogin)
            {
                UserDefaults.standard.set(logins + 1, forKey: "loginCount")
                UserDefaults.standard.set(Date(), forKey: "lastLoginDate")
            }
       }      
        window.rootViewController = ViewController() // Main flow controller.
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        self.window = window
    }  
    else
    {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(Date(), forKey: "lastLoginDate")
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "launchedBefore")
        UserDefaults.standard.set(1, forKey: "loginCount")

        window.rootViewController = introViewController() // Onboarding controller.
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        self.window = window

    }
```

Comment: I call it in  `func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {`

I wonder if the issue is that this is not called if my App stayed active in th background overnight ....? Should I call from somewhere else?

It's hard because I can't keep leaving it overnight to test my hunches!

Comment: If you login you also need to logout, right? Since your login only seems to be about writing to UserDefaults you need to supply this logic yourself. There might be a shortcut though depending on what exactly it is you are counting, you could compare the date in UserDefaults with the current date and if it is not the same then you have a “new” login.

Comment: To clarify, when I wrote not the same I meant not the same day.

Comment: The code I wrote uses `if !myCalendar.isDateInToday(lastLogin)` to check the logic to increase the count - it's just it didn't increase last night.

My question is two parts:
1) Any obvious reason why
2) Is there a way of testing my code other than waking up each morning and checking hopefully

Comment: You need to check lastLoginDate before you check launchedBefore if you don't have any specific logout logic that resets launchedBefore. Actually, I wonder if you even need launchedBefore or if you can get by with checking the date only?

Answer (score 0):

I figured my error.

My code is correct - but it needs to be placed in
`func sceneWillEnterForeground(_ scene: UIScene) {` .
Before it was in
`func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {`
which is not called when the app is backgrounded and then reopened.